# Dask dataframe sql_read of a mariadb database got " IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, types, dask

I have a read_sql_query which retrieves a Dask Dataframe.  This issue is in the table I have Nan/None values and I am trying to convert to 0, so that I can export it to csv.  When I try I get a "IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer" I have tried [NaN values not replaced into dask dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469413/nan-values-not-replaced-into-dask-dataframe), this.

However, I am still getting the error.

```
    #####-----
        #variables
        connection_string = 'mysql+mysqlconnector:......'
        indexColumn = mytitle + '.' + myrefcolumn
        desc_txt ='{0} desc'.format(indexColumn)
    

        
    #####-----
        #STEP 1 - SQL Query
        sql_query = sql.select(['*']).select_from(
                sql.table(mytitle)
            ).order_by(text(desc_txt)).limit(mylimit)

        #STEP 2 - read table
        data = dd.read_sql_query(sql_query, connection_string, index_col=myrefcolumn)

        #STEP 3 - replace Nan
        data = data.replace(to_replace=np.nan, value=0)
        data = data.replace(to_replace=np.inf, value=0)
        #data = data.replace(to_replace=np.isfinite, value=0)
        #---
        data = data.replace(to_replace='nan', value=0)
        data = data.replace(to_replace='NaN', value=0)
        data = data.replace(to_replace='inf', value=0)
        data = data.replace(to_replace='NA', value=0)
        data = data.replace(to_replace='Na', value=0)
        data = data.replace(to_replace='None', value=0)
        data = data.replace(to_replace='NULL', value=0)
        data = data.replace(to_replace='NULL', value=0)
        data = data.replace(to_replace=' ', value=0)
        #data = data.replace(to_replace=None, value=0)
        data = data.fillna(0)
        
        #STEP 4 -- load / merger dataframes
        data_merge = dd.merge(dataA, dataB, on = ['idColumnA','idColumnB'], how = 'inner')

        #STEP 5 - exporting to csv
        data_merge.to_csv('csv_testing/data*.csv',  index=False)
```

My question, is there another way, to fix this that I am not aware of.  Or, I am not well versed in python Sqlachemy on a way to filter out the Nan/None in the query and replace it with zero in the query or just not add the row.

I tried Step 3 from [NaN values not replaced into dask dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469413/nan-values-not-replaced-into-dask-dataframe)

Comment: First, you might want to set `head_rows` to a much bigger number than 5 when calling `read_sql_query`. If it sees a version of NaN, it should make the output dtype a float or masked int rather than int, and your problem would go away. You can also provide a `meta` to explicitly specify your output dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to...

```
#STEP 2 - read table
data = dd.read_sql_query(sql_query, connection_string, index_col=myrefcolumn, divisions=None, npartitions=None, limits=None, head_rows=300, meta=None)
```

I changed exporting it as csv to parquet but get.

```
#STEP 5 - exporting to parquet
all_merged = all_merged.repartition(partition_size="800MB")
all_merged.to_parquet("_testing/__all_merged.", schema=None).
```

But now I am getting, that it times out at Step 5 and I get the response.

> OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) 2055: Lost
> connection to MySQL server at '127.0.0.1:3306', system error: 104
> Connection reset by peer [SQL: SELECT * ...... [parameters:]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).